# Create dataframe of plotlys in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been using the below code to create a df of plotlys in R.

In this example, one plotly for each species from the iris dataset.

However the `do` function from dplyr has been superceeded so want to update the code.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

plots<-. %>%
plot_ly(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)%>%
add_markers()

df_plotly<-iris%>%
   group_by(Species)%>%
   do(plotly_objects=(plots(.)))
```

The documentation says replace `do` with `summarise`, `nest_by` and `across` however I can't see how to apply those functions to this code.

How can I rewrite the above code to replace the `do` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ultimately ended up solving this problem:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

plots<-. %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)%>%
  add_markers()

df_plotly<-iris %>%
  nest_by(Species,.key = "nested_data") %>%
  mutate(p = list(plots(nested_data)))
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of reformatting this works well using `purrr::nest` and `dplyr::mutate`:

```r
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

plots<-. %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)%>%
  add_markers()

df_plotly <- iris %>%
  nest(data = -Species) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(plotly_objects = list(plots(data)))

df_plotly
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   Species    data              plotly_objects
#>   <fct>      <list>            <list>        
#> 1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]> <plotly>      
#> 2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]> <plotly>      
#> 3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]> <plotly>
```